# Register non-static method with PyMethodDef

Tags: c++, boost-python, python-c-extension

I am looking for a way to register non static methods of my MyWidget class as python methods.

MyWidget class is a QWidget class and it's on the main window. So I want to initialize
python when the app is launched then I want to retrive information from MyTableWidget (QTableWidget)
within MyWidget class. I like to register itemCount non-static method as python method. I could not do it
since non static object registration gives error on myPythonCommands below.

I checked boost::python but could not find a way to do it. It's doc cover to create a python clas within
C++ but not his one as far as I know.

I was wondering if any of you know a way and point me to right direction?

```
class MyTableWidget
{

};

class MyWidget
{

    MyWidget()
    {
        Py_Initialize();
        Py_InitModule("myApp", myPythonCommands);
    }
    ~MyWidget()
    {
        Py_Finalize();
    }

    int itemCount()
    {
        return table.itemCount(); //return item count (in table) to python
    }

    MyTableWidget table;
};
static PyMethodDef myPythonCommands[] = {
                                            {"itemCount",  itemCount, METH_NOARGS, ""}, // here is the register part
                                            {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
                                        };
```

Comment: Is that even possible? For that you'd need a member function pointer, i.e. `MyWidget::*`, which is a different type of pointer than what the Python/C API can accept. I think a better approach would be to define a new Python object type that wraps `MyWidget` and define a member function for it that calls `itemCount()` on the wrapped object.

Comment: Well, that's my problem anyway. I am a python developer myself not C++ so my knowledge on the issue is very limited. Would you please point a document which covers defining a new Python object ans wrapping it for this kind of purpose, or similar example? Ther should be a logical way to do it, it would be weird if this can not be done in a proper way. Do not wanna think that no class member can be reached for Python embedding. Again, my knowledge is very limited, forgive me if I am stating something wrong. Thank you for your post.

Comment: The documentation is http://docs.python.org/extending/, and specifically this section: http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics. I won't be able to write proper and complete answer to describe this now, but perhaps the examples given in the documentation suffice.

Comment: Hi again, Thank you very much for the links. Those a bit make sense to me however I am still not able to get the whole idea of wrapping mywidget by creating a new python object. I have checked the documents and as far as I understand even if I create a python object (ends up being a class) all the methods belong to it are actually static functions in c++ anyway. So at this point I could not figure out how to actually connect mywidget to the code in C++. Is there any example on the internet that you know directly related to this kind of purpose? Very much appriciate your time on this. thanks